# How to get a measure like standard deviation from imresize on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Say I have an array of MxN size (M and N are arbitrary) in MATLAB, which I want to downsize to (M/a)x(N/b) size.

I can do that using `imresize` function, however, I need an additional measure. I would like to know what is the standard deviation (or a similar measure) of the pixels of the old image that formed each of the binned pixels of the new image.

Could you please point me to any direction?

Comment: You should be able to compute the standard deviation of the image before and after resizing. Why exactly do you need this or what are you hoping to find?

Comment: hi, I am not interested in knowing the std of the whole image before and after (which is straight forward). Let's say A is my original matrix (4x4) and B is my scaled matrix (2x2), given by `imresize`.

I would like to have a C matrix which will be again 2x2 which would contain the standard deviation (or generally the intensity variation) of each 4 pixels of A that were used to calculate each pixel of B.

I hope it makes more sense

Comment: @user3367364 It's much better to include that information in your question rather than comments. I am still not entirely sure what you want to do. You have a much higher chance of getting a useful answer if you create a small complete and verifiable answer that will clearly demonstrate you problem (i.e. an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the method of resize but maybe you can try this? if the images is `I` and the resized images is `Ismall`

```
Isquared = I.^2;
IsqSmall = imresize(Isquared,size(Ismall));
Istd = sqrt(IsqSmall-Ismall.^2)
```

This is since

```
sigma = sqrt(sum(x.^2)-mu.^2)
```

Comment: just to avoid numerical problem try
Istd = sqrt(abs(IsqSmall-Ismall.^2))
or Istd = sqrt(max(IsqSmall-Ismall.^2,0))